# How to set condition in relational models

Tags: yii, get, many-to-many

I have two tables named `content` and `category` that have `MANY_MANY` relation like this:

```
'contents'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Content',
                'content_category(category_id, content_id)',
                'order'=>'contents.id DESC',
    )
```

content_category is a medium table between these two tables. So I use this relation to find contents of a category like this:

```
$category = Category::model()->findByPk($cat_id);
foreach ($category->contents as $content)
{
    //some code for each content
}
```

Now I want to write some condition out of relation, for `content` table, in order to, this relation find some contents. and my condition may be various and get them from `$_GET` variables.
how I must write my condition

Comment: Have you tried looking through SO? [Some variation of this question has been asked about 80 times already.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yii+condition+relation) You could also try reading the documentation. It is all there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CDbCriteria to do this. Here's a simple example:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'the columns you need';
$criteria->limit = 5; // the number of row to fetch
$criteria->condition = 'column=:param OR column2="example"';
$criteria->params = array(':param' => $_GET['param'];//bind the param to the condition

//here I am going to add some conditions about the related model
$criteria->with = array(
   'content' => array(
       'select' => 'the columns you need in the related model',
       'condition' => 'column=:param',
       'params' => array(':param' => $_GET['param']),
   ),
);

$category = Category::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Read the Yii documentation about [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) to find more options. The [yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record) has also some examples